# Use the context of a component in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I have a problem- I try to use **reactScrollbar**, but the package has the `scrollTop()` function in the context.

I have this:

```
<ScrollArea
   speed={0.5}
   className="scroll-container"
   contentClassName="container"
   smoothScrolling={true}
   horizontal={false}
   onScroll={(value) => this.handleScrollWheel(value)} >
```

I want to do something like:

```
handleScrollWheel = (value) => { 
   this.context.scrollArea.scrollTop();
}
```

The context is undefined. Any solutions?

Comment: It looks like `this.context` is a property of the content within the `<ScrollArea />` [See the docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar#refresh)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register to the `context` of ScrollArea:

From the [DOCS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar#context)

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ScrollArea>
                <Content />
            </ScrollArea>
        );
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleSomeAction.bind(this)}> Some long content </div>
        );
    }

    handleSomeAction(){
        this.context.scrollArea.refresh();
    }
}

Content.contextTypes = {
    scrollArea: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

Keep in mind that this is using [the legacy context API of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html)

Comment: yes i read this, but i already inject `value` so how can i do this : `this.handleScrollWheel(value).bind(this)`

Comment: that doesn't matter, the context gives you the ability to access props of the the provider no matter how deeply nested the component (consumer) is

Comment: well, i do `onScroll={this.handleScrollWheel.bind(this)}`, and i still get my `value` but `this.context` is still an empty array. Did `Content.contextTypes = {***}` is usefull for make it work ?

Comment: Of course, this is the way to subscribe to the context.

Comment: This logic should be inside a child of the scroll area component. Same as the example i provided. Only children can access a context of a component

Comment: i try to add `myComponent.contextTypes = {**}` right before the export line so after the close tag of my myComponent class, and it result to `Cannot read property 'object' of undefined` this is sad.

Comment: `myComponent` should be a child of the `ScrollArea` if you want to use its cobtext

Comment: for now i only have several div and some text as child, i cant use it without make a class who group all my content ?

Comment: If you want to use `context.scrollArea.someMethod` you will need to register to the `context` that `scrollArea` exposes to it's children, so in other words only children of `scrollArea` can get access to its `context`. by the way i don't see any point to invoke `scrollTop()` inside `onScroll`, whenever a user will start scrolling it will just scroll to top. that actually will prevent scrolling won't it?

Comment: i want to use it with an animation, like if the scroll is bottom and a var is === to something i change the content and then reset the scroll to top. So I cant use it with the onScroll function ? :(

Comment: okay just find a tricky solution, i add class who put my height to 0 for 1s, and it reset the scroll